# How to group array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to group similar objects with the same label.

At the moment, this is the the JSON I receive.

```
const sizes = [{
        id: [{
            value: '2496',
            label: 'XS'
        }, {
            value: '2499',
            label: 'S'
        }],
        type: 'First Size'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '2863',
            label: 34
        }, {
            value: '2866',
            label: 36
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '3561',
            label: 'XS'
        }, {
            value: '3563',
            label: 'S'
        }, {
            value: '3565',
            label: 'L'
        }, , {
            value: '3567',
            label: 'XL'
        }]
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '3523',
            label: 34
        }, {
            value: '2866',
            label: 36
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }]
```

The result I am trying to achieve is

```
const sizes = [{
        id: [{
            value: '2496,3561',
            label: 'XS'
        }, {
            value: '2499,3563',
            label: 'S'
        }],
        type: 'First Size'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '2863,3523',
            label: 34
        }, {
            value: '2866',
            label: 36
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '3565',
            label: 'L'
        }, , {
            value: '3567',
            label: 'XL'
        }]
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '2866',
            label: 37
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }]
```

I have tried to achieve this with underscore, but I am only able to group it by just one label, and I need to group it by any kind of label, whether it be XS or 36.

I have tried with reduce below, it is close but I just need to remove the brackets around the value, and turn the value into a string.

EX:   value: '2493, 2343'

```
var group_to_values = sizes.reduce(function     (obj, item) {
    obj[item.label] = obj[item.label] || [];
    obj[item.label].push(item.value);
    return obj;
}, {});

var groups = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {label: key, value:    group_to_values[key]};
});
```

[image]

Comment: what is actually the difference? what about typeless types?

Comment: The difference is that the result I'm trying to achieve has two values for XS, which is grouped.

Comment: @anon Have you tried anything yet? Show us your code.

Comment: @Ivan I have edited and did what I tried, but just trying to remove the brackets around the value

Comment: why does the wanted result has four objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table for same labels and iterate the outer array and the inner array. If a label is not found, it generates a new entry for the result set.

```js
var sizes = [{ id: [{ value: '2496', label: 'XS' }, { value: '2499', label: 'S' }], type: 'First Size' }, { id: [{ value: '2863', label: 34 }, { value: '2866', label: 36 }], type: 'Shoe Sizes' }, { id: [{ value: '3561', label: 'XS' }, { value: '3563', label: 'S' }, { value: '3565', label: 'L' }, { value: '3567', label: 'XL' }] }, { id: [{ value: '3523', label: 34 }, { value: '2866', label: 36 }], type: 'Shoe Sizes' }],
    labels = Object.create(null),
    joined = sizes.reduce((r, a) => {
        var temp;
        a.id.forEach(o => {
            if (labels[o.label]) {
                labels[o.label].value += ',' + o.value;
                return;
            }
            if (!temp) {
                temp = Object.assign({}, a, { id: [] });
                r.push(temp);
            }
            temp.id.push(labels[o.label] = o);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(joined);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, the code below would output Array called `result`, which is data set you desired, the loop is clear so I think it won't be an issue for you to go through it:

```js
const sizes = [{
        id: [{
            value: '2496',
            label: 'XS'
        }, {
            value: '2499',
            label: 'S'
        }],
        type: 'First Size'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '2863',
            label: 34
        }, {
            value: '2866',
            label: 36
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '3561',
            label: 'XS'
        }, {
            value: '3563',
            label: 'S'
        }, {
            value: '3565',
            label: 'L'
        }, {
            value: '3567',
            label: 'XL'
        }]
    }, {
        id: [{
            value: '3523',
            label: 34
        }, {
            value: '2866',
            label: 36
        }],
        type: 'Shoe Sizes'
    }]

var groupedSizes = {};
for (var current, i=0;i < sizes.length ;i++){
  for (var j=0;j < sizes[i]['id'].length;j++) {
    current = sizes[i]['id'][j]
    if (groupedSizes[current['label']] !== undefined) {
      groupedSizes[current['label']].push(current['value'])
    } else {
      groupedSizes[current['label']] = [current['value']]
    }
  }
}
var result = []
for (var key in groupedSizes) {
    result.push({'id': groupedSizes[key].join(','), 'label': key})
}

console.log(result)
```