# Reorder/Group Array based on Key/Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a tricky task based on the JSON I receive (image below)

What I'm trying to do is group the label together

**XL** should be together with **XS,S, M, L** as the last array.

And, **37, 39, 41** should be in the same array as **34, 36, 38, 40, 42**...but in the correct numerical order from least to greatest.

Currently I'm trying to attempt this with code, which I'll paste here when I get some attempt.

[image]

Comment: didn't you ask the same question about a month ago?

Comment: Add please jsfiddle code sample with an example json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064503/how-to-group-array)

Comment: I'm working on a code sample.